# cannot format the installed HDFS

Tags: macos, hadoop

I tried to install Hadoop on my mac but there is a problem when it comes to format HDFS, when I execute the command `hdfs namenode -format`,

it shows Error:

> Cannot execute /Users/Apple/Documents/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/hdfs-config.sh.

Comment: Have you verified that the file exists, that it's executable, and that your user has permission to execute it?

Comment: Why are you using Hadoop 1.2.1? Hadoop 3.0 is the latest stable version... Hint: `brew install hadoop`